# who arrived first in satyug?

Tags: mahabharata, krishna, ramayana, rama

who  arrived first in satyug ?

Lord Ram or lord krishna

According to  [this](https://www.brahma-kumaris.com/shri-krishna-birth)

Lord krishna arrived first in satyug  but Valmiki written ramayan  before  Ved Vyas- Mahabharat

So here  im   confused

Comment: thanks u @Archit  exaclty...im reading now